# Flex Swfloader with a swf which loads another swf file

Tags: apache-flex, swfloader

I have one Swfloader. This swfloader loads file A.swf.
On creationComplete event, File A.swf loads another swf(file B.swf).

Everything works fine when I run the application once in the same machine.

But when I run two or more instance of the application, the first works fine (both file A and B are loaded) but the second swf (file B) is not loaded by file A.

Could you please help me to find out why the first swf (file A) doesn't load file B, when the application is running in multiple instance ?

Thank you in advance,

Casey

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. There could be a few explanations.  First off, have you tried debugging your problem?  It could be something to do with browser caching.  I would look at your developer console (included with Chrome, ctrl+shift+i, or use Firebug extension with Firefox) in the Net panel to see if it's loading the new swf properly or not.

Are the swf being loaded dynamically with data or is it static (b.swf never changes).  There are too many things to take into consideration here, but it could be that there's an error that happening and it's not loading b.swf.  Do you have Flash Player debug installed?